# Only got +1 Reputation from answer upvote

Tags: support, down-votes, reputation, up-votes

I recently posted an answer to a [question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/95937/is-this-a-bad-habit-of-work-after-job-day/95943#95943). After that I proceeded to read the other answers; upvoted one I considered good and downvoted another that was not so good and also seemed like was somewhat promoting a product.

After the downvote, I was able to see the usual -1 reputation from casting my vote. Some minutes later, someone upvoted my answer, but was confused to see that I only got +1 from it, when it should be +10. This is what I see:

[image]

Is this a bug of some sort? Will it eventually all sync up and appear the usual +10? Does it have something to do with the fact that I achieved 200 reputation on this day and somehow caped my reputation gain?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Does it have something to do with the fact that I achieved 200 reputation on this day and somehow caped my reputation gain?

Yes, that's exactly it. You reached your 200 rep max for the day, preventing you from receiving reputation from any more upvotes. Then you downvoted a question, which cost you 1 reputation. At that point you had earned a net +199 reputation, allowing for you to gain +1 rep the next time someone gave you an upvote.

Comment: Thanks @David K , this seems to be the reason why. I also found [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work) and [this other](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8086/how-to-get-over-200-reputation-points-every-day) questions that pointed me to the conclusion you also arrived. It seem that the maximum is only for **upvotes and edits**, one can still get more than 200 rep from other actions. Also, this "lost" reputation is not gained on future days...